# Accessing a server side text file Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, share, fileserver

I am trying to read a simple text file from a share drive on my internal network.

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Users/myName/Desktop/App_Data/text.txt"; 

    NSFileManager *filemgr;

    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:filePath] == YES)
        NSLog (@"File exists");
    else
        NSLog (@"File not found");
```

I have a shortcut to the folder called App_Data on my desktop which is connected to the server but the actual file is on the server and cannot access the file through the shortcut folder.  I am trying to do this for an iPad using Objective-C.  Is there a better method to access the server?

Comment: The code you posted is not accessing a server for anything, it will just be looking in the specified folder on the iPad itself.

Comment: I understand, so how do i make it look for the server files verses the iPad files.  I dont know how to differentiate between the two.

Comment: The simulated iOS doesn't have access to your Mac filesystem.

Comment: is there a way i can save and access my data to a server that the iPad is connected to? I was hoping to compile an online database that could be accessed by the iPad as well as modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run an FTP server on the machine with the file(s) you want to access and create an FTP connection to that from the iPad.

Here is a "simple" FTP example from Apple, [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html), using both the NSURLConnection and CFFTPStream APIs.